# How to make sure only one text field is not empty?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a text field, which i check to make sure the text field is not empty before submission, which work fine.

How do I make sure that it only checks for the **id="Name"** text field is not empty and ignore the other text field.

```
<input type="text" class="form-control"  id="Name" aria-label="Name"  placeholder="Name" required >   

<input type="text" class="form-control"  id="address" aria-label="address"  placeholder="address">   

<input type="text" class="form-control"  id="zip" aria-label="zip"  placeholder="zip" >
```

JS

```
$('input:text').val().length;
```

Comment: Do you mean `$('#Name').val().length;`?

Comment: `$('#Name').val().length;`

Comment: Use the right selector for the job. See [here](http://www.w3schools.com/jquery/jquery_ref_selectors.asp) for a list of jQuery selectors. As other have pointed out `$('#Name')` will select the element you want to target.

Comment: @Theo to be honest, I am not even sure if that's what OP means. He's a >2.5k  rep user with the most answers in the jQuery, followed by JavaScript and then CSS. It seems like the sort of thing that he should know, so I don't know if I'm genuinely missing something about using the ID selector.

Comment: Besides using the correct selector, the OP probably doesn't want a field that is just full of empty space either, so `$("Name").val().trim().length`; is probably called for

Comment: @vlaz I was taking the question at face value - I dint even look at the reputation. Now that you point it out, the question does not seem commensurate with the person asking it ...

Answer (score 2):

Target the element by ID,

```
$('#Name').val().length;
```

Comment: if html tags allowed, this will not work. For example text field can have <span></span> tags but it has not any string value. So checking should be with regex to handle tags. But if you assume only valid string, this is acceptable.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try this?

```
$('#Name').val().length;
```

Comment: if html tags allowed, this will not work. For example text field can have <span></span> tags but it has not any string value.

Comment: @hakkikonu you can say that for _any_ single piece of jQuery ever written. "But what if the ID you are targetting changes?" I believe the answer will always be that it doesn't matter. It's impossible to code for any situation ever - what if the select you were trying to style gets changed to a div? What if the CSS rule for an `h1` element stops t apply to it when you change it to a `p`? There is always some structure a developer should expect in the HTML they manage. In most circumstances HTML won't magically change without your involvement.

Comment: While this may answer the question, it doesn't provide any context to explain how or why. Consider adding a sentence or two to explain your answer and how to use it.

Answer (score 0):

You have set attribute `required` to the input with ID `Name` so `form` won't submit unless it has some value. If you want to check for whitespaces you can use jquery [$.trim()](https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.trim/) method:

```js
$('form').submit(function(e) {
  var name = $('#Name').val();
  if ($.trim(name) === '') {
    e.preventDefault();
    return false;
  }
  console.log('form submited!');
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form>
  <input type="text" class="form-control" id="Name" aria-label="Name" placeholder="Name" required />

  <input type="text" class="form-control" id="address" aria-label="address" placeholder="address" />

  <input type="text" class="form-control" id="zip" aria-label="zip" placeholder="zip" />
  <input type="submit" value="submit" />
</form>
```